# Mixing up casing, but keeping it consistent

Tags: syntax

There is a general opinion that whatever casing style you pick for yourself, just make sure to be consistent with it. Let's say I want to mix it a bit, but still keep it technically consistent, such as camelCase for functions, and snake_case for variables. Is this still acceptable, or is this frowned upon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly want to keep to the industry standards for the language(s) you are using.  Any teams you work with will most likely use these, and remaining consistent among your team greatly improves readability and maintainability.

If you are doing your own project, I would still recommend sticking to those standards.  It's simply better to maintain the habit for when you do eventually work as part of a team.

Most industry naming conventions are as you describe.  One case standard for variable names, another for function names, another for class and namespace, etc etc